# How to get the query string from the URL to my scraper

Tags: c#, web-scraping

i'm currently building a scraper that gets data from an airlines website.

```
https://www.norwegian.com/uk/booking/flight-tickets/farecalendar/?D_City=OSL&A_City=RIX&TripType=1&D_Day=17&D_Month=201910&dFare=57&IncludeTransit=false&CurrencyCode=GBP&mode=ab#/?origin=OSL&destination=RIX&outbound=2019-10&adults=1&direct=true&oneWay=true&currency=GBP
```

My objective is to get a link from each of these calendar days (from 1 to 31)

I am using a HTTP Analyser and if I pass a query it returns this in the Query String window :

```
/pixel;r:1875159210;labels=_fp.event.Default;rf=0;a=p-Sne09sHM2G2M2;url=https://www.norwegian.com/uk/ipc/availability/avaday?AdultCount=1&A_City=RIX&D_City=OSL&D_Month=201910&D_Day=17&IncludeTransit=false&TripType=1&CurrencyCode=GBP&dFare=57&mode=ab;ref=https://www.norwegian.com/uk/booking/flight-tickets/farecalendar/?D_City=OSL&A_City=RIX&TripType=1&D_SelectedDay=01&D_Day=01&D_Month=201910&IncludeTransit=false&CurrencyCode=GBP&mode=ab;fpan=0;fpa=P0-2049656399-1568351608065;ns=0;ce=1;qjs=1;qv=4c19192-20180628134937;cm=;je=0;sr=1920x1080x24;enc=n;dst=1;et=1568366731754;tzo=-60;ogl=
```

How do I pass each of these queries to a scraper?

EDIT: I should've probably said that I need the program to loop through each flight and change the day (in this case from 1 to 31) in the URL.

My scraper is pretty basic, it can do basic websites that have links and it can show things like Titles, Articles, etc..

I should probably add that my aim is to display the destination, prices, time for travel, etc... which are something that I would know how to do.

Hope you can understand this. Thanks!

This is what I currently have and I will modify it to suit my needs.

```
public void ScrapeData(string page)
        {
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load(page);

            var Articles = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class = 'article-single']");
        foreach (var article in Articles)
        {
            var header = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(article.SelectSingleNode(".//li[@class = 'article-header']").InnerText);
            var description = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(article.SelectSingleNode(".//li[@class = 'article-copy']").InnerText);
            Debug.Print($"Title: {header} \n + Description: {description}");

            _entries.Add(new EntryModel { Title = header, Description = description });
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Use of any automated system or software to extract data from this website for commercial purposes is prohibited" - just in case this isn't for a personal project.

Comment: A company has issued me a homework to do for a job, which is exactly this. none of the data used is going to be used for commercial use, at least not by me.

Answer (score 0):

That URL returns a calendar comprised of buttons with the fare info and day on them, so you'll have to parse the returned HTML to find the individual day and then the fare from that cell.

So it seems easy to hit the URL, then loop through each table cell in the calendar section for the sub-divs in the DOM that contain the relevant day and fare info. Fortunately they have an aria-label for both these items so they are easy to locate.

Comment: Are there any examples of this exact thing? Could you please provide some example code?

Comment: Open up your browser, look at the "web developer" tools. Its all in there.

Comment: Yes, I know that much, but the issue is how do I keep looping the program so it replaces the URL with a different day until it reaches 31.